Cant make a realease of a mirrored CI-Component
I am new at GitLAB and my task is to use GitVersion Ultimate Auto Semversioning
Since we are using private gitLab instance I have to mirror component in my repository
How can you show the catalog in self-managed instances?
Using official documentation I successfully managed to mirror a repository to my own gitlab instance: Use a GitLab.com component in a self-managed instance
I am stuck at point 5: Publish a new release in the self-hosted component project by running a pipeline for a tag (usually the latest tag).
Official gitlab-ci.yml
include:
  - component: $CI_SERVER_FQDN/guided-explorations/ci-components/ci-component-pub/release-ci-component@2.2.2

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_TAG'
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
      when: always  

# now I need to add this for a release (below is a link)
create-release:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  script: echo "Creating release $CI_COMMIT_TAG"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
  release:
    tag_name: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    description: "Release $CI_COMMIT_TAG of components in $CI_PROJECT_PATH"


I added from documentation create-release.
I got these errors:

Unable to create pipeline
component 'gitlab.trikoder.net/guided-explorations/ci-components/ci-component-pub/release-ci-component@2.2.2' - content not found

I am guessing I need to point it to my mirrored component on my private GitLAB instance.
include:
component: "gitlab.<my_gitlab_domain>/components/ultimate-auto-semversioning/ultimate-auto-semversioning@1.2.8"
Next I got an error:

Unable to create pipeline
create-release job: chosen stage does not exist; available stages are .pre, build, test, deploy, .post

I created release stage, and I got this

No GitVersion.yml detected, creating a minimal one to avoid version
duplication problems... mode: Mainline running git version and setting
version in pipeline variables using dotenv artifacts bash: line 163:
/tools/dotnet-gitversion: No such file or directory Uploading
artifacts for failed job
WARNING: thisversion.env: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact
path is relative to the working directory
(/data/gitlab-runner/builds/SeKSAQDi/0/components/ultimate-auto-semversioning)
ERROR: No files to upload

Can someone help please?
